# Inserting new EmailMessageRelation records cause Task Deletion/Cloning

Tags: apex, email

We have enabled EnhancedEmail in our org.

Inbound email is created into Task, EmailMessage and EmailMessageRelation records.

Attached is the data model between User, Task, EmailMessage and EmailMessageRelation.

After inbound email is processed, it will be as shown below.

[image]

If I insert a new EmailMessageRelation record (*a new CCAddress for the email message..in the example lets say I add User U2*), **the associated Task (T1) gets deleted and an replica Task (T2) is cloned**.

[image]

Is this behaviour expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Salesforce user perspective, any question related expectedness is looking for documentation stating so. I haven't seen such documentation.

Tasks are feeble things. Tasks are re-created all the time. Any change of the EmailMessage will re-create the Task. Any update of existing EmailMessageRelations will re-create the Task (and [updates are what Salesforce seems to favour](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395054&type=1)).

(As you probably noticed, EmailMessageRelations are created automatically. Not sure in which situation some of the addressees of an incoming email message might not be known during EmailMessage insertion. Instead of inserting EmailMessageRelations, the update of the EmailMessage seems to work just as well.)

The Task is not cloned, but replaced by a brand new one according to Salesforce's liking.

I was wondering, if an update of the Task makes any difference, but even a status "Completed" didn't stop Salesforce from re-creating the Task. Neither made it a difference, if "shared activities" is activated on an org.

What can we do? The ActivityId of the EmailMessage can't be updated, i.e. not temporarily knocked off to hide some secret EmailMessageRelation
action from Salesforce's sight.

Only thing that comes to mind: Take a snapshot of the Task before you start out and update it afterwards. Which will not reinstate
System fields etc., but might be the best you can do.

Most of my answer is based on what I remember from the past and lunch break experiments. I haven't found much documentation. So take it with a grain of salt ;-)

Comment: _Tasks are feeble things_ - Salesforce records are so transient and ephemeral, lemme tell ya.